# Python bs4 div class with same name issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

A website has the same name for different div class like so:

```html
<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="boggart">
<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="wand">
<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="patronus">
```

```py
for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    blood_status = article.find('div', class_='pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color')
```

So when I run this code, I'm getting only the first div class. My question is, how can I get the 3rd div class only?

The URL: https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Ronald_Weasley.

So I want to select the boggart div class and get "Spider" in return.

Comment: have you tried, article.find_all(), instead of find()

Comment: Yes but this returns every item under the every div class. Is there a way to find by href?

Comment: find(), method returns the first element and find_all() returns all elements.
you can use **find_all(href=''text here')**

Comment: can you send website url?

Comment: with find_all() it returns all elements but I only want a specific div class not all of them, this is the issue i'm having. the url is: https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Ronald_Weasley

Comment: @AlejandroViete please [edit] your question and include the `URL` within it. and describe the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.find(text="Boggart").find_next("a").text
    print(target)


main("https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Ronald_Weasley")
```

Output:

```
Spiders
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example for your reference.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils

html = '''
<article>
<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="boggart"></div>
<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="wand"></div>
<div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="patronus"></div>
</article>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
articles = doc.selects('article')
for article in articles:
  print(article.select('div@data-source=patronus'))
```

Result:

```
{'class': 'pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color', 'data-source': 'patronus', 'tag': 'div', 'html': ''}
```